# paypal express checkout stop redirecting to paypal site

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal-express

The problem is i need to stop redirecting to paypal after the selecting the payment method as paypal because it was missing the order review step so i want this to come to order review step and accept terms and condition and then redirect to paypal. So please help me to solve this issue i am using magento 1.7

Comment: You can also review order when you return after formalities on paypal website.

Comment: But my requirement is like i stated above :(